# How to create a charge with Stripe for a Wordpress website?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have managed to create a Checkout Button for my Wordpress Site (using Divi) to accepts my customer's payment details and directly passes them to Stripe's servers.

Now, I need to create charges using Stripe’s API and my server-side code to process charges.

I am quite lost here having never done this before. Could someone tell me by step by step how to proceed?

Comment: The best place to start would be [Stripe Elements Quickstart](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart) and let us know if it doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Maybe you could consider using a plugin for wordpress like: https://nb.wordpress.org/plugins/stripe/

You dont seem that familiar with PHP so i highly recomend using a plugin instead.

EDIT:
If you prefer to make this yourself take a look at stripe docs here: https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart and maybe consider looking at this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EildM6OMcoQ (This guy is awesome)

Comment: Take a look at my edit: If you prefer to make this yourself take a look at stripe docs here: https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart and maybe consider looking at this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EildM6OMcoQ (This guy is awesome)